# Can I assume that the Windows profile directory is not writable by other users?

Tags: windows

Can I assume that the Windows profile directory is not writable by any user other than the user my program is running under and the system administrator (who can access anything)?

More specifically:

The [SlipRock](https://github.com/DemiMarie/SlipRock) library creates a directory `~/.sliprock`.  This directory contains temporary files, which in turn contain (among other things) a secret access key.  Therefore, if other users are able to read these files, the result is a security vulnerability.

The directory is created with [strict permissions](https://github.com/DemiMarie/SlipRock/blob/5ee7c8c8a3f24fb8cc75a7eea06f72b5cb8fc627/src/sliprock_windows.h#L121) that deny access to untrusted code, but these are moot if another user could rename the directory.  Can I be confident that a user’s home directory (as returned by `GetUserProfileDirectory`) is a secure directory?

Comment: Good question to ask. Actually, RENAMING an NTFS directory doesn't change the permissions since those perms are bound to the directory object regardless of the name and if it is changed.  Did you mean  "moot if another user could TAKE OWNERSHIP OF the directory" instead of rename?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `%UserProfile%` is a secure directory in such a way, that it's protected from being read or altered by other users in the default configuration.

It is not a secure directory, in such a way that any system administrator including backup operators, holder of various privileges (SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege, SeTcbPrivilege, ...), anyone who can access the files offline, etc. can read, and in most cases, alter the files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be confident?  Only if you know the permission scheme in that install of Windows!

By default, non-admin users don't have rights to other users' profile directories.  However, many unskilled administrators make all users administrators in order to simplify software and driver installation.  Also, you'd want to check that some rogue administrator hasn't given permission to your home directory to other users and that other users don't have rights to elevate processes.  (They could use that to elevate Powershell or CMD, for instance, and then browse your home directory).

Comment: In that case I am sunk anyway :P.  I am assuming a reasonably configured system where security against other users is possible at all.